# What's the unix command to replace parts of the stdout output of one binary with the output of another?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Let's say one binary outputs "hello [your name]" and the second binary outputs "Bob". How do I output "hello Bob" and then pipe that input as a flag to a THIRD binary? I'd imagine I use sed but I don't have a clue after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)

```
$ echo 'hello [your name]' | sed 's/\[your name\]/'"$(echo "Bob")"'/' | cat -n
     1  hello Bob
```

Comment: Thanks! When I replace echo "Bob" with my command that runs a c++ binary that prints to cout it doesn't work, however. The character is replaced with an empty string even though the binary certainly outputs a real string.

Comment: Does the output contain any forward or backward slashes?

Comment: It does. It also has quotes. I guess those should be escaped.

Comment: For the forward slashes use a different delimiter with sed. The backward slashes will need to be escaped. The quotes shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to write it. Here's 2 of them.

Using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
prog1 | sed -f <(echo -n 's/\[ your name\]/'; prog2; echo '/') | prog3
```

Using [variable substring replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) without sed.

```
a=$(prog1)
b=$(prog2)
prog3 <<< "${a//\[your name\]/$b}"
```

Hope this helps.